# Object-like utility type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a built-in type in Typescript for such type:

```
interface ObjectLike {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

I have tried looking at documentation but haven't found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

```js
type ObjLike = Record<string, string>
```